# Obtaining the P value from t

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, t-test, multivariate-analysis, t-distribution

I am not really familiar with the student’s t distribution. My problem is highlighted in picture, the variables I have obtained are ‘tj’, ‘rj’, N(number of data points) and k(number of predictors) but I don’t really know how to calculate ‘pj’ which is referred to in the picture.

I would appreciate any sort of help, I’ve been stuck of this part for 2 days now.
[image]

Comment: As it says you either look it up in tables or you use a software function. The former seems old-fashioned these days and the latter depends on which software you use.

Comment: I’m using MATLAB, but if you know how to perform this using any other software please guide me. Much appreciated

Comment: I am afraid questions on how to use software are seen as off-topic here and I do not use Matlab anyway. Perhaps there is a Matlab forum you could ask on?

Comment: Is there an equation or a table you could guide me on how to calculate it manually without a software. Sorry for a lot of questions

Comment: I think you will find many tables on the internet. Try typing student t table into your favourite search engine and see what comes up.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, there is a MATLAB tag you can add if that is the preferred method of solution.  I suspect the function you may need is tcdf or tinv, tinv will give you the threshold based on a p-val, 1-tcdf can give you the pval for a calculated statistic